# Is it possible to inject spring data jpa repository into java persistent entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to inject spring data jpa repository into java entity (using hibernate to declare POJO as persistent entity)?

I have Person java entity model like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PERSON_ID",nullable=false)
    private UUID personId;
    ...
```

Here is spring data jpa repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,UUID> {
    @Query("from Person where Person.id = ?1")
    Person findPersonById(UUID id);
```

Comment: If you really want Rails-style Active Records, look at GORM, but Active Record makes business logic a serious pain to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and you should never do it. JPA entities are handled from within the JPA providers lifecycle. The JPA specification explicitly forbids performing any database operations from within the PrePersist, PreUdate and so on listeners. Doing anything related to active persistence from inside the entity might have unexpected side effects.

About the question if it is possible at all. Everything is possible :) does not mean it is a good idea though.

You will not have control over how hibernate or spring data is initializing those entities though. Entities are **not managed** by spring so if you want to actually do some dependency injection there you would need AspectJ involved performing code weaving.